# Datastax Cassandra OpsCenter service not starting on Windows 7

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I am new to Cassandra. I installed DataStax Cassandra community edition on Windows 7  64 bit by following the instructions mentioned in [DataStax Community Edition](http://www.datastax.com/2012/01/getting-started-with-apache-cassandra-on-windows-the-easy-way). I following exactly same instructions, but for some reason I could not about connect to OpsCenter. Then I went and trying to start OpsCenter service manually. I am getting the following error.

> Windows could not start the DataStax OpsCenter Community 2.0.6 on 
>   Local Computer. For more information, review the System Event Log. If
>   this is a non-Microsoft service, contact the service vendor, and 
>   refer to service-specific error code1.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

### Thanks

### **Initial Logs**

INFO [main] 2014-03-14 11:01:53,329 Starting Jetty server: {:port 61621, :host nil, :ssl? false, :join? false}
  INFO [Initialization] 2014-03-14 11:01:53,356 New JMX connection (127.0.0.1:7199)
  INFO [Initialization] 2014-03-14 11:01:53,374 New JMX connection (127.0.0.1:7199)
  INFO [Jetty] 2014-03-14 11:01:53,393 Jetty server started
 ERROR [Initialization] 2014-03-14 11:01:53,416 Exception in thread "Initialization" 
 ERROR [Initialization] 2014-03-14 11:01:53,418 clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: throw+: {:type :bad-permissions, :message "Unable to locate the cassandra.yaml configuration file. If your configuration file is not located with the Cassandra install, please set the 'conf_location' option in the Cassandra section of the OpsCenter cluster configuration file and restart opscenterd. Checked the following directories: [\"/etc/dse/cassandra/cassandra.yaml\" \"/etc/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml\" \"/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml\" \"C:\\Program Files\\DataStax Community\\utils\\conf\\cassandra.yaml\"]"} {:object {:type :bad-permissions, :message "Unable to locate the cassandra.yaml configuration file. If your configuration file is not located with the Cassandra install, please set the 'conf_location' option in the Cassandra section of the OpsCenter cluster configuration file and restart opscenterd. Checked the following directories: [\"/etc/dse/cassandra/cassandra.yaml\" \"/etc/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml\" \"/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml\" \"C:\\Program Files\\DataStax Community\\utils\\conf\\cassandra.yaml\"]"}, :environment {tar-location "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\utils\conf\cassandra.yaml", conf nil, checked-files ["/etc/dse/cassandra/cassandra.yaml" "/etc/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml" "/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml" "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\utils\conf\cassandra.yaml"]}}
 ERROR [Initialization] 2014-03-14 11:01:53,418     at opsagent.util.cassandra_util$cassandra_conf_location.invoke(cassandra_util.clj:118)
 ERROR [Initialization] 2014-03-14 11:01:53,418     at opsagent.util.cassandra_util$get_cassandra_conf.invoke(cassandra_util.clj:130)
 ERROR [Initialization] 2014-03-14 11:01:53,418     at opsagent.opsagent$create_thrift_conf_vars.invoke(opsagent.clj:52)
 ERROR [Initialization] 2014-03-14 11:01:53,418     at opsagent.opsagent$setup_thrift.invoke(opsagent.clj:138)
 ERROR [Initialization] 2014-03-14 11:01:53,418     at opsagent.jmx$determine_ip.invoke(jmx.clj:341)
 ERROR [Initialization] 2014-03-14 11:01:53,418     at opsagent.jmx$setup_jmx$fn__1359.invoke(jmx.clj:358)
 ERROR [Initialization] 2014-03-14 11:01:53,419     at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
 ERROR [Initialization] 2014-03-14 11:01:53,419     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
 ERROR [StompConnection receiver] 2014-03-14 11:01:54,309 failed connecting to 127.0.0.1:61620:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
  INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2014-03-14 11:01:54,569 Reconnecting in 2s.

---

copied and added the cassandra.yaml file into the utils\conf and now getting the following errors in the log file

**New Logs**

INFO [conf-requester] 2014-03-17 12:10:16,209 Requesting latest conf from opscenterd
  WARN [clojure-agent-send-off-pool-44] 2014-03-17 12:10:16,209 Tried to send message while not connected: /conf-request [["fe80:0:0:0:f905:968a:ba35:a65f%19","fe80:0:0:0:20c3:67db:49f9:631d%15","fe80:0:0:0:c0e8:7cb:589d:e349%17","0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1","192.168.16.214","fe80:0:0:0:901d:eb95:fb56:2fa8%13","fe80:0:0:0:0:100:7f:fffe%14","192.168.152.1","192.168.168.1","fe80:0:0:0:c52b:50f7:e159:d639%12","127.0.0.1"],["4.1.1","/1895607593/conf"]]
 ERROR [StompConnection receiver] 2014-03-17 12:11:15,128 failed connecting to 127.0.0.1:61620:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
  INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2014-03-17 12:11:15,128 Reconnecting in 60s.
 ERROR [StompConnection receiver] 2014-03-17 12:12:16,130 failed connecting to 127.0.0.1:61620:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
  INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2014-03-17 12:12:16,130 Reconnecting in 60s.
 ERROR [StompConnection receiver] 2014-03-17 12:13:17,137 failed connecting to 127.0.0.1:61620:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
  INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2014-03-17 12:13:17,137 Reconnecting in 60s.
 ERROR [StompConnection receiver] 2014-03-17 12:14:18,140 failed connecting to 127.0.0.1:61620:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
  INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2014-03-17 12:14:18,140 Reconnecting in 60s.
 ERROR [StompConnection receiver] 2014-03-17 12:15:19,152 failed connecting to 127.0.0.1:61620:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
  INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2014-03-17 12:15:19,152 Reconnecting in 60s.
 ERROR [StompConnection receiver] 2014-03-17 12:16:20,156 failed connecting to 127.0.0.1:61620:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
  INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2014-03-17 12:16:20,156 Reconnecting in 60s.
 ERROR [StompConnection receiver] 2014-03-17 12:17:21,159 failed connecting to 127.0.0.1:61620:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
  INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2014-03-17 12:17:21,159 Reconnecting in 60s.
 ERROR [StompConnection receiver] 2014-03-17 12:18:22,162 failed connecting to 127.0.0.1:61620:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
  INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2014-03-17 12:18:22,162 Reconnecting in 60s.
 ERROR [StompConnection receiver] 2014-03-17 12:19:23,175 failed connecting to 127.0.0.1:61620:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
  INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2014-03-17 12:19:23,175 Reconnecting in 60s.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Installed it on 2 machines today (2.0.6 community) and can't start the opscenter.  The error in the eventlog is "The DataStax OpsCenter Community 2.0.6 service terminated with service-specific error Incorrect function.."

Comment: Can you go to the system log and paste the error message here?

Comment: Hey Daniel, Please find the above logs. Thanks

Comment: Can you paste the content of <installdir>\opscenter\agent\conf\address.yaml please?

Comment: stomp_interface: 127.0.0.1 
conf_location: "C:/Program Files/DataStax Community//apache-cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml"

Comment: I hope that's in two separate lines, and is that conf_location correct for your setup?

Comment: Ok, I can reproduce this, we are working on a solution. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: We should have a fixed msi out soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now a new version ready for download that has this issue fixed. Pleas give it a try. The issue is that the opscenter definition download code was unconditionally using ssl, which is not supported on Windows. Also address.yaml and local.conf now specify the proper location for the cassandra configuration file.

Thanks,
Sven

Answer (score 2):

Until they fix it, I can confirm a fix that worked for me:

I copied the 'conf' directories from `<installdir>/opscenter` and `<installdir>/apache-cassandra` to `<installdir>/utils`

Then, I also copied the 'OpenSSL' folder from `<installdir>/opscenter/lib-fallback/py-win32/2.7` to `<installdir>/opscenter/lib/py-win32/2.7`

I then started the 'DataStax OpsCenter Community' service manually, and successfully navigated to localhost:8888/ for the OpsCenter itself

As with any such hacks, please make sure you have full backups, I guarantee nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I took user3461142's solution (which worked for me) and wrote a bat file that created symbolic links so that if any of the config file change, you don't have to copy them to the "utils/conf directory"

```
REM create symlinks so that OpsCenter's Service will run
cd %ProgramFiles%\DataStax Community\utils
mkdir conf
cd .\conf

REM Create Links for Cassandra
mklink /J triggers          ..\..\apache-cassandra\conf\triggers
mklink cassandra.yaml           ..\..\apache-cassandra\conf\cassandra.yaml
mklink cassandra-env.sh         ..\..\apache-cassandra\conf\cassandra-env.sh
mklink cassandra-rackdc.properties  ..\..\apache-cassandra\conf\cassandra-rackdc.properties
mklink cassandra-topology.properties    ..\..\apache-cassandra\conf\cassandra-topology.properties
mklink cassandra-topology.yaml      ..\..\apache-cassandra\conf\cassandra-topology.yaml
mklink commitlog_archiving.properties   ..\..\apache-cassandra\conf\commitlog_archiving.properties
mklink log4j-server.properties      ..\..\apache-cassandra\conf\log4j-server.properties
mklink log4j-tools.properties       ..\..\apache-cassandra\conf\log4j-tools.properties
mklink rep2.bat             ..\..\apache-cassandra\conf\rep2.bat
mklink rep3.bat             ..\..\apache-cassandra\conf\rep3.bat

REM Create Links for OpsCenter
mklink /J clusters      ..\..\opscenter\conf\clusters
mklink /J definitions       ..\..\opscenter\conf\clusters
mklink /J event-plugins     ..\..\opscenter\conf\clusters
mklink install_id       ..\..\opscenter\conf\install_id
mklink install_type     ..\..\opscenter\conf\install_type
mklink log4j.properties     ..\..\opscenter\conf\log4j.properties
mklink opscenterd.conf      ..\..\opscenter\conf\opscenterd.conf
mklink ssl.conf         ..\..\opscenter\conf\ssl.conf

REM Create Links for OpenSSL
cd ..\..\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7
mklink /J OpenSSL ..\..\..\lib-fallback\py-win32\2.7\OpenSSL
```

**Note** this assumes you installed Cassandra in your default program files directory. Use at your own risk!