# Cassandra OpsCenter Agent doesn't work after restart on Windows 8

Tags: windows, cassandra, windows-services, datastax, opscenter

I installed Cassandra from DataStax on Windows 8 and it worked fine. I could use the database itself and could use the OpsCenter without issues.
Then i restarted the computer, and the OpsCenter started giving my this message:

```
Error: ClusterManager instance has no attribute 'sub_services'
```

Cassandra is working fine, but the OpsCenter isn't. I start the service on the service manager and it suddenly stops.

I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22410760/datastax-cassandra-opscenter-service-not-starting-on-windows-7), but it didn't work.

Since i'm learning to use Cassandra, i think the OpsCenter is a crucial visual tool for me.

Comment: Could you paste the whole log somewhere please?

Comment: @arre I'd be happy to, but which one? There are so many...

Comment: @Jorge the opscenterd.log file